# Why do I have "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special.cython_special'" when I don't even use cython?

Tags: python, cython, executable

I used pyinstaller to generate an executable for a python script, and when trying to run the executable I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.special.cython_special'`. I'm not sure where this is coming from, or how to fix it. My executable takes in one argument and returns a list. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Its originating from the `scipy` package, which is missing the dependency `cython_special`. I don't know anything about pyinstaller, but my intuition says that the generated executable does not have `scipy` and it's related dependencies correctly bundled.

Comment: You must be using `scipy`.  `scipy` uses `cython` a lot to interface python with compiled packages.  You may need to install a fuller 'development' version of `scipy` (and other packages).

Answer (score 6):

I had this error after freezing a program that used scipy  version 1.5.0  but I changed the version to 1.4.1 (which I had used with  an earlier virtual environment) and the error disappeared.

Comment: This worked. Do this and then sort out the next error pyinstaller throws.

Comment: @azazelspeaks that's totally rubbish I've spent 1 day on pyinstaller errors and I still have more! there should be an official package from python to handle all of this

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same error, and not exactly sure what causes it or why pyinstaller doesn't find that dependency, but you can fix it by adding 'scipy.special.cython_special' to your pyinstaller myapp.spec file like this:

```
a = Analysis(['/Users/Name/path/to/mystartupfile.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/Name/...'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('data')],
             hiddenimports=['scipy.special.cython_special'],
             hookspath=['/Users/Name..../hooks'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['IPython', 'FixTk', 'tcl', 'tk', '_tkinter', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added that line to my spec file, but I'm still getting the same error..

Answer (score 2):

Add `--hidden-import="scipy.special.cython_special"` to your pyinstaller command.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by copying the `cython_special.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file from `MyEnv>Lib>site-packages>scipy>special` into the same directory of the compiled pyinstaller program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out I was using Python 3.8 which isn't supported by Pyinstaller. Try using 3.7.

Comment: I downgraded from Python 3.8 to Python 3.7, however this didn't help me.  I did find that the problem went away after downgrading scipy to version 1.4.1, as per the answer provided by @profTC.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

Downgrading `scipy` package to 1.4.1 solved the issue as @profTC [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737264/12519655).

Alternatively, one can upgrade to `PyInstaller` 4.0 where they have added a new hook file to deal with this. See: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0/CHANGES.html#hooks

Another solution is to use to directly copy the [hook file](https://github.com/Jmennius/pyinstaller/blob/27c787ac438f72d537d3b075030a3c8a87277b96/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-scipy.stats._stats.py) and include it as an [additional hook when building](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0/hooks.html) with PyInstaller.